# My vue.js nav will not navigate to other pages, just reloads the same page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, navbar, href, nav

new to Vue js so hopefully it is simply something I have missed.

I have a navbar component, which generates a list of nav items like below:

```html
<template>
    <div class="nav-section">
        <nav>
            <span class="logo">D & E</span>
            <ul>
                <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
                    <a :href="item.href">{{ item.text }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</template>
  
<script>
import "./navbar.scss";

export default {
    name: 'NavBar',
    components: {
    },
    props: {
    },
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    href: "/homepage",
                    text: "Home"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    href: "/about",
                    text: "The Wedding"
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    href: "/story",
                    text: "Our story"
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    href: "/travel",
                    text: "Travel & Stay"
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    href: "/response",
                    text: "RSVP"
                }
            ]
        };
    },
    methods: {

    },
}
</script>
```

however, when i am clicking each link, this just looks like it reloads the homepage, so I can never actually see a new page (which is obviously not what I want).

Have I missed anything glaringly obvious with this?

To add, I have not got vue router installed in the project, not sure how this can be done or if it is even needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VueJS is an SPA, so you're not using traditional `a` tags to move from page to page (as you do in Wordpress realm for example, which is MPA).
Maybe give a read to [that one](https://medium.com/@NeotericEU/single-page-application-vs-multiple-page-application-2591588efe58) for more details.

If you want to move from page to page, you **need** to use [Vue router](https://router.vuejs.org/) as you guessed.
You need to define the routes in a `/router/index.js` file with something like this

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import CustomersName from "../views/CustomersName.vue";
import HomeView from "../views/HomeView.vue";
import AboutView from "../views/AboutView.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "index",
    component: HomeView,
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "about",
    component: AboutView,
  },
  {
    path: "/customers/:name",
    name: "customers-name",
    component: CustomersName,
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

And use `router-link` to move to that given page

```html
<router-link to="/about">about page</router-link>
```

I've just updated one of my [github repo](https://github.com/kissu/v2-router/blob/main/src/App.vue#L5) with a working configuration.
Clone the project locally and inspect how it works if you want more details.

Comment: Thank you! This half works, but when I navigate away from the homepage and try to get back, it just loads an empty white page, no content which should show. is there a reason for this? {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView
  },

Comment: @Dan the given repo works perfectly (I just double-checked). Please update your question with more details as to what is not working exactly. Because everything is fine on my side. Going from `/about` to `/` or something else?