# VUE: How to configure dynamical router URLs

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vite

it's my first time using Vue and I need to set a vue app on an existing and working webpage, using a relative path like `https://www.my-website.tld/lang/en/xxxxxxx` or `https://www.my-website.tld/xxxxxxx`

(xxxxxxx is a dynamical uri)

My router will be like that:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "sesiones",
      component: () => import("../views/SessionsList.vue")
    },
    {
      path: "/session/:id",
      name: "sessionid",
      component: () => import("../views/SessionId.vue"),
    }
  ],
});

export default router;
```

I need to know how can I generate the router (or vite.config.ts file) to make it possible.
The end result should be something like this:

If I access `https://www.my-website.tld/lang/en/xxxxxxx` it shows me the content of the router "/".

If I access `https://www.my-website.tld/lang/en/xxxxxxx/session/24` it shows me the content of the router /session/:id

Any one can help me? Is that possible?

I tryed with path, alias, base_url in config file

Comment: Hi, give a try to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74858416/8816585

Answer (score 0):

I think is solved.
I set the variable `base: './'` to the `vite.config.ts` and then, changed the path to the routes like that:

First one:
`path: "/:booking"`

Second one:
`path: "/:booking/:id"`